# Meaning of ぎゃほ ?

Tags: translation, interjections

What does the interjection ぎゃほ mean?

Context:
A: We are mentioned in (famous newspaper)
B: ぎゃほ！ かんどう＝＝＝＝３３３

Does it have the meaning of かんどう ? Or is it surprise, or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"ぎゃぼ" is one of the unique interjections used by Noda Megumi (野田恵), the main protagonist of the manga, anime and j-drama "Nodame Cantabile" (のだめカンタービレ) when she is surprised. She also uses "むきゃ" when irritated.

[image]

Comment: so ぎゃほ is a variation?

Comment: Probably. Also ぎゃぽ, ぎゃぼん, ぎゃぽん etc